# PHP: Check if 0?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, zero

I am using a class which returns me the value of a particular row and cell of an excel spreadsheet. To build up an array of one column I am counting the rows and then looping through that number with a `for()` loop and then using the `$array[] = $value` to set the incrementing array object's value.

This works great if none of the values in a cell are `0`. The class returns me a number 0 so it's nothing to do with the class, I think it's the way I am looping through the rows and then assigning them to the array... I want to carry through the 0 value because I am creating graphs with the data afterwards, here is the code I have.

```
// Get Rainfall
$rainfall = array();
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
{
    if($data->val($i,2) != 'Rainfall') // Check if not the column title
    {
        $rainfall[] = $data->val($i,2);
    }
}
```

For your info `$data` is the excel spreadsheet object and the method `$data->val(row,col)` is what returns me the value. In this case I am getting data from column `2`.

**[Screenshot of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCHuU.png)**

Comment: Try using var_dump() and print_r() on your data array. Those nifty functions are very helpful for debugging!

Comment: What happens when a 0 is found?

Comment: @John I have done so, which is why i am confused. I have 30 rows in the excel file and when i do a print_r on the array I only get the values that are not 0.. so it's as if it disregards 0

Comment: @Tommy, for some reason it doesn't add it into the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try an array_push() ?

```
array_push($rainfall, $data->val($i,2));
```

Comment: I am really surprised here. array_push() works but $array[] = $var; does not? Actually, array_push() for a single variable is nothing else then $array[] = $var; I thought?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a strict comparison with the [not identical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator here instead of using the not equals operator:

```
if($data->val($i,2) !== 'Rainfall')
```

If `$data->val($i,2)` is an integer and you use `==` both sides will be cast to integers which would give you the  result that all integers would work as you expect except for zero. Here's a summary of the difference between `==` and `===` when comparing the string "RainFall" with zero:

```
0 == "RainFall" : true
0 != "RainFall" : false
0 === "RainFall" : false
0 !== "RainFall" : true
```

Comment: Doesn't PHP get goofy with 0s and comparisons, meaning it treats a 0 as false instead of an integer in certain situations? I think I saw that somewhere before...

Answer (score 1):

I think that the array is treating the 0 like false, which could explain it not going into the array.  Would something like this work (if you are using integers)?

```
(int)($data->val($i,2));
```

or

```
(float)($data->val($i,2);)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the if statement. You're trying to compare a string with an integer, which according to the PHP documentation will typecast both to integers.

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number  and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

You can read more here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php.

Update: The if statement won't work in the case of `0` because `(int)"Rainfall"` will by typecasted into `0` by PHP causing the statement to be `if (0 != 0) { ... }`.

If `$i` represents the row number, why don't you start from 2 instead of 1?